# Internet Board Games

Tags: java, ide, applet, network-programming

Hello I'm looking to create a web-page where users can play Gomoku live with eachother, kind of like [instantchess.com](http://www.instantchess.com), or yahoo's online pool.

I would like to be able to..
1) Have the players to chat with each other while they play.
2) Have registered users where a ranking can be kept track of.
3) Users can create 'rooms' where another player and spectators can join.

Should I be using java applets for the whole page, Especially the networking?  If so, can someone point me in the right direction because I don't know how to have the applets interact with the server for database storage and live play/chat.

Also assuming I would be using java applets what IDE do you suggest?

Any Help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you use Java Applets, I would recommend building in Swing.  I do all of my development in Eclipse using their visual editor for rich application development, but I have heard positive things about NetBeans.

2) I would not recommend using applet technology.  It seems, currently, that Sun is on the verge of retiring that technology.  Instead, I would recommend a page based architecture.  You could use a framework like GWT or something similar.  I am certain other Stack Overflow members who are more familiar with web technologies can point you in a better direction than I can.  However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538550/pros-and-cons-of-various-java-web-presentation-layer-technologies) has a pretty good run down of a number of different web-presentation layer technologies.

Be aware you will need to talk to a database to do the behavior you have described.  Just an FYI if you were not aware.

Answer (score 1):

Also, your users are going to hate applets....because pretty much everyone hates Applets.

Answer (score 0):

audiodude is right, your users will hate applets.

Flash is defacto now.